# Scalability of OLAP Cubes - Impact of Rows/Columns, hierarchical order of attributes, empty/redundant attributes

Tags: scalability, olap, olap-cube, star-schema

In order to properly redesign some legacy OLAP cubes, I need to understand the general scalability and some specific drivers of OLAP cube speed:

- **General:** *How do OLAP cubes approximately scale for rows and columns (attributes)?* 
  e.g., I would assume something like n^2 or n^3 depending on attribute numbers.
- **Impact of hierarchical order:** *How does hierarchical ordering influence the calculation, storage and response time?*
  e.g., I would assume a day-month-year hierarchy to be way faster than considering the three as separate, independent attributes.
- **Special cases - empty and redundant attributes:** *How do empty attriubtes affect the cube calculation and usage speed? What about redundant attributes' influence?* 
  e.g., regarding the latter, I'd consider redundant to have an attribute country = USA and country code = US.